# Error: Form elements must not be named "submit"

Tags: php

Pequei um exemplo no github e estou tentando colocar imagens nos produtos,
criei uma `input[type="file"]` e esta me retornando este erro.

```
Error: Form elements must not be named "submit".
```

Mas se eu colocar o `input[type="text"]` faz o registro normal no BD.

**form.php**

```php
<div id="required_fields_message"><?php echo $this->lang->line('common_fields_required_message'); ?></div>
<ul id="error_message_box"></ul>
<?php
echo form_open('items/save/'.$item_info->item_id,array('id'=>'item_form'));
?>
<fieldset id="item_basic_info">
<legend><?php echo $this->lang->line("items_basic_information"); ?></legend>

<div class="form-group row">
<label   class="col-sm-4 col-form-label"><?php echo form_label($this->lang->line('items_name').':', 'name',array('class'=>'required wide')); ?></label>
    <div class='col-sm-8'>
    <?php echo form_input(array(
        'class'=>'form-control',
        'name'=>'name',
        'id'=>'name',
        'value'=>$item_info->name)
    );?>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Foto</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="img1" name="img1">
</div>

<?php
echo form_submit(array(
    'name'=>'submit',
    'id'=>'submit',
    'value'=>$this->lang->line('common_submit'),
    'class'=>'submit_button float_right')
);
?>
</fieldset>
<?php
echo form_close();
?>
```

**items.php**

```
function save($item_id=-1)
{

    $item_data = array(



    'name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
    'description'=>$this->input->post('description'),
    'category'=>$this->input->post('category'),
    'supplier_id'=>$this->input->post('supplier_id')=='' ? null:$this->input->post('supplier_id'),
    'item_number'=>$this->input->post('item_number')=='' ? null:$this->input->post('item_number'),
    'cost_price'=>$this->input->post('cost_price'),
    'unit_price'=>$this->input->post('unit_price'),
    'quantity'=>$this->input->post('quantity'),
    'reorder_level'=>$this->input->post('reorder_level'),
    'location'=>$this->input->post('location'),
    'allow_alt_description'=>$this->input->post('allow_alt_description'),
    'is_serialized'=>$this->input->post('is_serialized')
    );

    $employee_id=$this->Employee->get_logged_in_employee_info()->person_id;
    $cur_item_info = $this->Item->get_info($item_id);


    if($this->Item->save($item_data,$item_id))
    {
        //New item
        if($item_id==-1)
        {
            echo json_encode(array('success'=>true,'message'=>$this->lang->line('items_successful_adding').' '.
            $item_data['name'],'item_id'=>$item_data['item_id']));
            $item_id = $item_data['item_id'];
        }
        else //previous item
        {
            echo json_encode(array('success'=>true,'message'=>$this->lang->line('items_successful_updating').' '.
            $item_data['name'],'item_id'=>$item_id));
        }

        $inv_data = array
        (
            'trans_date'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'trans_items'=>$item_id,
            'trans_user'=>$employee_id,
            'trans_comment'=>$this->lang->line('items_manually_editing_of_quantity'),
            'trans_inventory'=>$cur_item_info ? $this->input->post('quantity') - $cur_item_info->quantity : $this->input->post('quantity')
        );
        $this->Inventory->insert($inv_data);
        $items_taxes_data = array();
        $tax_names = $this->input->post('tax_names');
        $tax_percents = $this->input->post('tax_percents');
        for($k=0;$k<count($tax_percents);$k++)
        {
            if (is_numeric($tax_percents[$k]))
            {
                $items_taxes_data[] = array('name'=>$tax_names[$k], 'percent'=>$tax_percents[$k] );
            }
        }
        $this->Item_taxes->save($items_taxes_data, $item_id);
    }
    else//failure
    {
        echo json_encode(array('success'=>false,'message'=>$this->lang->line('items_error_adding_updating').' '.
        $item_data['name'],'item_id'=>-1));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que você definiu um campo com `name="submit"` nesta parte:

```
<?php
    echo form_submit(array(
        'name'=>'submit',
        'id'=>'submit',
        'value'=>$this->lang->line('common_submit'),
        'class'=>'submit_button float_right')
    );
?>
```

> Error: Form elements must not be named "submit".

*tradução: Elementos de formulario não devem ser nomeados "submit"*

Assumindo que essa função `form_submit` gera um botão `html` remova a chave `name` ou altere o nome para qualquer outra coisa exceto `submit`, por exemplo:

```
<?php
    echo form_submit(array(
        'name'=>'send',
        'id'=>'send',
        'value'=>$this->lang->line('common_submit'),
        'class'=>'submit_button float_right')
    );
?>
```